# How do I send a post request starting from the base "/" route

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express, url

```
$(".auth-form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = $(this);
    const url = e.target.id == "register-form" ? "auth/register" : "auth/login";
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (textStatus, status) {
            if (url.split("/")[1] == "login" && textStatus.status) {
                getUser();
            }
            changeDOM(textStatus, url.split("/")[1]);
        },
    });
    // location.reload();
});
```

I'm trying to send a post request to /auth/login from url localhost:3000/user/saved. But when I try the code above it ends up sending a post request to localhost:3000/user/auth/login.

Comment: `url` should be `/auth/login`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing /auth/login before and got back an error message but it turns out the error had to do with something else. Thanks [bravo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10549313/bravo).